# Trouble to search and find the special " \ " character inside a string?

Tags: python, string

I have a list of people names (string elements) and some of them are corrupted with a backward-slash '\' sitting somewhere in the middle of their names.

I would like to filter them outside, but am finding hard-to-explain issues...

To look for the `\` backslash, I used `.find` method or `in`, they both seem to work identically.

The only parameter that seems to work is `"\\"`, because `"\"` or `r'\'` will both result in error (escaping the final quote --> `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`)

Therefore, this is the search code:

`names = ["robert", "rob\xadt", "egi\xadio"]
for name in names:
    print(name.find('\\'))`

*This will return -1, -1, -1 (nothing found)*

I cannot change the input string containing these names, however, for the sake of this issue, if I manually take one of these names and add the `r` *raw* before, then the code works, as in the last element below:

`names = ["egi\xadio", r"egi\xadio"]
for name in names:
    print(name.find('\\'))`

*This will return -1, 3 (found something!)*

I tried adding the raw symbol `r` systematically, but did not work, as below:

`name = 'rob\xadt'
name = fr'{name}'
name.find('\\')`

Finally, both 'similar' codes below will not find the `\`, but I wonder why the first one results in error:

`name = "rob\xar"
name.find('\\')`

**SyntaxError:** *(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-5: truncated \xXX escape*

`name = "rob\xad"
name.find('\\')`

*ok*

**Any insights?? Thanks in advance!**

Comment: `'\xad'` is `'­­-'` character.

Comment: This are UTF-8 characters encoded...

Answer (score 1):

```
name = r"rob\xar"
name.find('\\')
```

I think that this is what you want.
Here, 'r' means 'raw' string.

> String literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and use different rules for interpreting backslash escape sequences.

ref: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals